# android activity class does not exists?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have been developing a project in eclipse for an android app. An error which i frequently get is that of- activity class does not exist. But when i just save the manifest file once again the error vanishes and the program runs correctly. Why then do i get the same error again and again. ?

Console error:

```
[2011-11-18 15:08:38 - link] Starting activity acb.abc.LinkActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-11-18 15:08:40 - link] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=acb.abc/.LinkActivity }
[2011-11-18 15:08:40 - link] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2011-11-18 15:08:40 - link] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {acb.abc/acb.abc.LinkActivity} does not exist.
```

Comment: Clean and Build the project & then try running..

Comment: @Kartik just tried still no working

Comment: This happens to me sometimes when renaming packages. Sometimes when not everything gets properly refactored. Solves easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

every time a new activity is added in the application, it needs to be added in the manifest file as well with a new  tag.
Make sure that u r doing this otherwise the new activity will not be considered.
For reference see [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: I have my manifest fully updated.! Its just that i go to the manifest, make an error, save it then it runs fine!

Comment: what do u mean by "make an error"? what kind of error do u make here?

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem today.

Attention that: "class {acb.abc/acb.abc.LinkActivity}"，you should modify the `AndroidManifest.xml`, change `acb.abc.LinkActivity` to ".LinkActivity".  Then will be OK.

Comment: it's better to provide the fully qualified class name rather than the relative class name

Answer (score 1):

You are not declairing your package name correctly in your manifest, thats what I guess. Either post your manifest or go through this discussion.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ce62996fde2d4727

Cheers.....!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In may case, in Android Studio, I changed `AndroidManifest.xml` like this: change `main` Activity on my custom Activity. Then I start my app on emulation device, I get:

> "Error type 3 Error: Activity class {...} does not exist.",

and may app failed.

I was forced delete my app on virtual device (use Application Manager in device) and restarted app in Android Studio. This solution helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error because I had installed my app as a built-in app, then disabled it to removed it. I thought I had removed it when I tried to run my app in eclipse as a "normal" app. I discovered that my app was still in system/app.

Once I removed it, I didn't see this error when running my app in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too and it was because i had a second  tag in my AndroidManifest.xml
on android studio <= 0.8.6 it was no problem

i'm not sure yet how to handle this if one needs two application's defined here

my use case was related to saving the application state in a separate activity
e.g.
http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/126377651/global-application-state-in-android

Answer (score -2):

Error: Activity class {com.myapplication5.myapplication/com.myapplication5.myapplication.MainActivity} does not exist.

answer:
file-projectstructur-flavors-minsdk version =4
ok