# Error: Activity class {} does not exist

Tags: android, android-ndk

My application launches well both on Nexus 7 and Nook Tablet, but doesn't start on Kindle Fire with the following error:

```
Error: Activity class {com.js.pathoflight/com.js.pathoflight.JSNativeActivity} does not exist.
```

Here is my manifest complete:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.js.pathoflight"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="0.8.3">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:hasCode="true" >

    <activity android:name=".JSNativeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="PathOfLight" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

It seems like a device issue, but I have another (similar) application which runs on the same device well. 
How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this happen as soon as you clcik on the launcher icon?

Comment: Try changing the `<activity android:name=".JSNativeActivity"` to `<activity android:name="com.js.pathoflight.JSNativeActivity"` maybe it needs the full path.

Comment: @user3182577 Thank you for suggestion, that's another issue. I inserted the full path, but the error remain absolutely the same.

Comment: @JoxTraex I got this message when I try to launch the application from the IDE (I use Visual Studio + NSignt Tegra). Deployment seems to finish OK, but I can't see the application on the device. When I try to install .apk from the device I got laconic "Application not installed" message and no useful informaiton in the log.

Comment: You should decompile the apk and ensure that your class file for this Activity is present. Sounds likes its failing the Install portion, you should read what the PackageManager is saying (if anything at all).

Comment: 然而并没有什么卵用   -  - ------------------------

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real problem was that there were another application with the same package name on device (I tried a sample and gave it my real app package name)! When I removed it everything became working right!

Comment: i have too issue. delete my version apk in my mobile and run again. work fine.