# Error while Launching activity after deleting app from phone

Tags: android

I deleted my test app from my phone. Now I try to run app again within android studio. I expected that it would recreate the app. Instead I get this error:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=mobapptut.com.camera2videoimage/.LoginActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {mobapptut.com.camera2videoimage/mobapptut.com.camera2videoimage.LoginActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

How can I address this?

Comment: What device and OS version do you use?

Comment: LG Stylo2. Android Version 6.0.1 @Mike

Comment: please try adb uninstall <package>.

Comment: Hi Donato, could you accept an answer if they helped you? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check the "Deploy application" checkbox in the Run/Debug Configuration screen, under the General tab like is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071271/activity-class-does-not-exist)?
Try also a clean a rebuild and check that you do not have in Gradle 
 `apply plugin: 'android-library'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
"adb uninstall sample_package_path"
This has worked for me in older OS versions(*sometimes the app doesn't uninstall properly*)
Multiple users in O OS can also be the possible cause for this type_3 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Apps settings and delete it from there
**Settings -> Apps & Notifications -> See all Apps** (delete for all users):
As you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530648/session-app-error-launching-activity).